# Epson XP-2100 printer driver breaks Mac OS X El Capitan boot

Tags: startup, printing, driver

I have a Macbook pro 2009 running both Mac OS X El Capitan and Ubuntu 21.04 and an Epson XP-2100 Wifi printer and scanner.

Installing the [Epson recommended printer driver](https://www.drivers-epson.com/epson-expression-home-xp-2100-driver/) produces an error that was automatically reported to Apple.

The printer driver file :

```
mac2009% shasum /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ 
X/Users/alba/Downloads/Epson-Expression-Home-XP-2100-printer-driver-for-mac.dmg
e0012206ea2a471542134dfffb4e04491eb3d67a  /Volumes/Mac OS 
X/Users/alba/Downloads/Epson-Expression-Home-XP-2100-printer-driver-for-mac.dmg
```

(Epson does not publish any hash of the file, which leaves a possibility of corruption.)

Thereafter, printing works but Mac OS X El Capitan does not boot any longer.  Booting in verbose mode stops with

```
AirPort: Limnk Up on en1
Got incomplete channel sequence length 0, should be 16
en1: ...
en1: ...
en1: ...
Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1.single user mode
```

(I did not copy the ends of the lines beginning with `en1:`.)

Does anybody have an experience on another machine with El Capitan or another version of Mac OS X?

(On my machine the bug is reproducible after reinstalling Mac OS X.)

How to repair the Mac OS X system (apart from reinstalling) and safely install the printer driver  ?

Comment: I've no idea how to actually fix your issue, but .dmg files should be self-checking, so if it opens, it's not corrupt.

Comment: RE: "(Epson does not publish any hash of the file, which leaves a possibility of corruption.)" --  If they do not publish a _checksum_, then why are you even checking it? BTW I download the _file_ and got the same _checksum_ you did.

Comment: If you can boot into single user mode and know what files to delete that may help but it would depend on what the driver did to the system. Failing that just installing the same OS over top of what is there leaves all of your files intact, down to settings. It just *refreshes* macOS replacing only system files.

Comment: Can you boot to **safe mode**? If you can, then you can uninstall what was installed.  To boot to **safe mode**: 1. Turn on or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key as your Mac starts up. 2. Release the key when you see the login window, then log in to your Mac. 3. You might be asked to log in again. On either the first or second login window, you should see ”Safe Boot” in the upper-right corner of the window.

Comment: Otherwise I'd boot to **OS X Recovery**, **⌘R** at startup, and then from **Terminal** delete the, e.g.,  `rm -r '/Macintosh HS/Library/Extensions/EPSONUSBPrintClass.kext'`

Comment: Yes the dmg should be self-checking displaying "Verifying..." but this one does not.

Comment: I have found another driver here https://www.epson.fr/support?productID=27260&os=31#drivers_and_manuals  installing witthout error but it still breaks the boot!

Comment: RE: "Yes the dmg should be self-checking displaying "Verifying..." but this one does not." --  It shows it for me, however, if it stops your system from booting then the _checksum_ or the _verifying_ on the **.dmg** is irrelevant. --  Were you able to boot to **safe mode**?

Comment: I am unable to boot in safe mode.  The machine is dual boot so I must select the boot volume by pressing alt.  Then pressing shift for safe mode booting does normal (indeed failing) boot.  Nevertheless I can easily mount and modify the file system otherwise.

Comment: Removing `/Library/Extensions/EPSONUSBPrintClass.kext` does not solve the problem.  Does the installer have a log file?

Comment: I can boot in single (root) user mode with command S.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one: https://i.imgur.com/WOVW6Bf.png

Comment: OK I erred.  Removing `/Library/Extensions/EPSONUSBPrintClass.kext` does make the Mac OS boot again.  I could not find a Terminal in recovery mode but I did it by booting on external device.

Comment: RE: "I could not find a Terminal in recovery mode" -- It's in the **Utilities** _menu_ on the  _menu bar_.

Comment: Yes I just found out too.

Comment: I can also boot in safe mode.  Press alt, select boot volume, then press shift, enter, release shift at login window.

Comment: With the repaired system, in verbose mode, the Airport error message disappears so I suspect that the driver breaks in particular Airport.

Comment: Single user mode is read-only, not good for removing files.